# Ping works, but I get 'No route to host' even though my firewall is off

Tags: iptables, routing, firewall, telnet, nc

I want to check if I can connect to Rspamd's Fuzzy port and have a very strange problem - I can `ping` a the host and get an answer (0% packet loss). But when I try to `telnet` him, I get "**No route to host**":

```
# telnet 88.99.142.95 11335
Trying 88.99.142.95...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

And the same with `nc`:

```
nc -vz 88.99.142.95 11335
mail.highsecure.ru [88.99.142.95] 11335 (?) : No route to host
```

Sure, at first glance this looks like a firewall problem, but refer to the following output (the firewall is completely off - better said, there are no blocking rules):

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
# iptables -v -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 98 packets, 6560 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 64 packets, 5736 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I'm on a server virtual machine with Debain 10.

Has anyone an idea where the problem might be?

Comment: This is your host firewall or target machine's one?

Comment: @DevilaN - I'm trying to connect from a Server - there's no Firewall. And regarding the target machine - maybe.

Comment: So most probable answer here is that target machine firewall is blocking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target port is blocked by the target firewall (at least for your and my IP addresses).

If you run `tcpdump -i any -n icmp` then you see a `host unreachable - admin prohibited` ICMP packet.